# Assigned value to indices of numpy arrays changes to zero in while statement in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am assigning values to arrays in a while loop. take XM array for example. It has been initialized at the beginning of the program as:

```
XM = YM = A = np.zeros((500,3))
```

each member of the array must be assigned a value in a loop as:

```
XM[M][1] = XM2
XM[M][0] = XM2 - XD / 3.0
XM[M][2] = XM2 + XD / 3.0
```

where M is iterated to the last possible value for the array.
None of the arrays in the loop can hold the new values.
I used debug to find the reason for that behavior.
After the value is assigned everything is fine. but as soon as the next line of code is run, all values in the array are set to zero.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem with my code.
Arrays are reference values. I had mistakenly initialized all the arrays simultaneously. I corrected the mistake by changing initialization one by one as follows:

```
XM = np.zeros((500,3))
YM = np.zeros((500,3))
A = np.zeros((500,3))
```